# How to clarify whether the user's input was a binary number?

Tags: java

I was required to make a code that accepted a binary number (1's and 0's) and then counted how many ones were in that binary number. My code fulfills this purpose.

The second part of the exercise is this: if the user enters a number that is NOT binary, I must output that there is an error and keep prompting the user until they give a binary number.

Can someone show me how to incorporate this? I have tried several times but cannot make it click. Thanks! Here is my code.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class NewClass
{
public static void main( String [] args )   
{
 Scanner scan = new Scanner( System.in);

 int i = 0, count = 0;
 String number;

 System.out.println("Please enter a binary number.");
 number = scan.next();

 String number1 = "1";


 while ((i = number.indexOf(number1, i++)) != -1) {
     count++;
     i += number1.length();
 }
 System.out.println("There are "+ count + " ones in the binary number.");






 }
```

}

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please take some time to visit the [help] and also read [ask].  Questions of the form "here's my code, please debug it" are considered off-topic. StackOverflow is not a discussion, tutorial or debugging site. The way this works is you are expected to attempt to solve the problem and then ask for help when you run into a difficulty, explaining clearly what you have tried and what you don't understand. At a minimum you should already have stepped through the code in an IDE debugger and be able to identify results that don't match your expectation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You already know how to find all of the 1's; you should be able to do something similar to find all of the 0's.

If the sum of those two counts is not the length of the string, there must be at least one illegal character in it.

Answer (score 0):

If you use the [parseInt](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt(java.lang.String,%20int)) method you can do

```
Integer.parseInt("1100110", 2) returns 102
```

or in your case

```
int intVal = Integer.parseInt(number, 2);
```

as per the javadocs

```
Throws:
NumberFormatException - if the String does not contain a parsable int.
```