# How to show an error message for invalid user input?

Tags: java

My program’s purpose is to receive a binary number (1’s and 0’s) as input, verify that it is a binary number, deny the input if it is not a binary number and continue prompting the user until they enter a binary number, and then output how many ones and zeros are in that binary number.

Here’s the problem I am running into: While my program does output how many ones and zeros are in the number, even when I do enter a proper binary number, my output still says “ERROR: Not a binary number.” For example, if my input was 10001, the output would be this-

Please enter a binary number.
10001
There are 2 ones in the binary number.
There are 3 zeros in the binary number.
ERROR: Not a binary number.
Please enter a binary number.

What did I do wrong in my code?

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class NewClass
{
public static void main( String [] args )   
{
Scanner scan = new Scanner( System.in);

 int i = 0, count1 = 0, count0 = 0;
 String number;

 System.out.println("Please enter a binary number.");
 number = scan.next();

 String number1 = "1";

while ((i = number.indexOf(number1, i++)) != -1) {
     count1++;
     i += number1.length();
 }

    System.out.println("There are "+ count1 + " ones in the binary number.");


    String number2 = "0";

 while ((i = number.indexOf(number2, i++)) != -1) {
     count0++;
     i += number2.length();
   }
    System.out.println("There are "+ count0 + " zeros in the binary number.");


    int total = (count1 + count0);
    int length = number.length();

 if (length != total);
 {
     System.out.println("ERROR: Not a binary number.");
     System.out.println("Please enter a binary number.");
     number = scan.next();


 }


 }
```

}

Comment: Can you properly indent and format this code?

Comment: Why are you asking the same question again?

Comment: `if (length != total);` as per @jordanGS there should be no semicolon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code. First, you can use scan.nextLine() method to get user's input.
and Second, you don't need use two while loops separately for zeros and ones.
finally, if there is wrong input such as 2, 3 or else. It should be loop infinitely.

```
import java.util.Scanner;


public class NewClass {

public static void main(String [] args) {

    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    int i = 0, count1 = 0, count0 = 0;
    String number;

    char number1 = '0';
    char number2 = '1';

    int total;

    while(true){
        System.out.println("Please enter a binary number.");
        number = scan.nextLine();

        char [] charArray = number.toCharArray();

        while(i < charArray.length){

            if(charArray[i] == number1){
                count0++;
            } else if(charArray[i] == number2) {
                count1++;
            }
            i++;
        }

        total = count0 + count1;

        if(charArray.length == total){

            System.out.println("There are " + count0 + " zeros in the binary number.");
            System.out.println("There are " + count1 + " ones in the binary number.");
            break;

        } else {
            System.out.println("ERROR: Not a binary number.");
        }


    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you notice in your original code you had `if (length != total)**;**{` the `;` broke your if statement so it always triggered.

```
    int total = (count1 + count0);
    int length = number.length();

    if (length != total)
    {
        System.out.println("ERROR: Not a binary number.");
        System.out.println("Please enter a binary number.");
        number = scan.next();
    }
```

My suggestion would be to however use a boolean function to check if it's binary such as the following.

```
public static boolean isBinary(int number) {
    int copyOfInput = number;

    while (copyOfInput != 0) {
        if (copyOfInput % 10 > 1) {
            return false;
        }
        copyOfInput = copyOfInput / 10;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40476765/how-to-clarify-whether-the-users-input-was-a-binary-number

Comment: Well i provided a solution regardless, he had an extra `;` at the end of the `if (length != total)` which didn't work. That is a really bad school assignment tho *shrugs* :/

Answer (score 0):

I would check that the string only has 0s and 1s using a regex:

```
String number = "10001";
if (number.matches(".*[^01].*")) {
    System.out.println("ERROR: Not a binary number.");
}
```

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40476765/how-to-clarify-whether-the-users-input-was-a-binary-number